# Is there a limitation on how many webhooks can I create in a Pusher app?

Tags: pusher, webhooks

In the project my team is working we will set up two independent apps on the server-side, one is a django app and the other one is a tornado app. Both should be notified by webhooks when clients subscribe/leave a presence channel.

Will this be a problem? can we create as many webhooks to different URLs as we want to?

Comment: I don't believe there is a limit set on the number of WebHook destinations you can create (I used to work for Pusher). However, I'm sure that the number is not ∞. Best check with Pusher support. Would be very handy for you to answer your own question so others know too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the Pusher team (and I have to say they were very fast in giving me support) I learnt that there is not and established limit for this but they monitor it so you can't use as many as you want.

I asked if it is ok to have webhooks for 2 diferent URLS (for 2 different servers) and a total of 4 webhooks (cause we will need both channel existence and presence events webhooks) and they answered me that I won't have any problema at all with this configuration.